# Showing ID in url and fetching info to profile.php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create website with possible login and register functions ( I have it already ), I need to get ID in url and fetch data from the database.
I want it to look like this.

```
Bob
City: Berlin
Age: 16
Anna
City: Moskva
Age: 16
```

When Bob click on Anna's profile php needs to fetch her data and same for Bob.
There is what I get from url
`/profile.php?id=`
Here is code for ID

```
<a href="<?php header('Location: profile.php?id='.$row['id']);
exit; ?>" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Profile</a>
```

Is this code above good in <a href=>? or it needs to be written in `profile.php`

Comment: Need the mysql query and the looping code.Share that as well

Comment: That's not good. An a-tag is a link where `href=""` should contain an URL which the client gets redirected to when the link is clicked. `header('location: foo.com');` is a redirect which will redirect the client immediately. Also, `header()` calls must be made before anything is outputted at all, which means that this should throw "headers already sent" warnings.

Comment: @reaLFOXY you wrote in question - When Bob click on Anna's profile php needs to fetch her data and same for Bob. so how Bob knows it is click on Anna's profile Page???

Comment: @Dharman I use md5

Comment: MD5 is not suitable for passwords. Please read the links I provided and learn how to do it correctly. The privacy of your users is at stake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to pass id using url and get the data in profile.php page by passing id then use `$_GET[id]` super Global Variable.

```
<a href="profile.php?id=$row['id']">
```

And you can get that data using `$_GET[id];

**profile.php Page :-**

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `id`=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['city'];
echo $row['age'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I have this error now. ```mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in```

Comment: ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'id']'' at line 1
```
What this error mean?

Comment: @reaLFOXY it means your problem is in SQL Query , please echo it & run it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @KUMAR here is 

```$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'weekta');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM weekta WHERE `id`=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you code will work. The `header()` command sets a header and yes, it can redirect but not in an `<a>` tag.
Try something like this `<a href="/profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Profile</a>`

Update: If you want to know how to fetch and loop through data from your database, this might help you:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'name of db');
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<a href="profile.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Visit '.$row['username'].'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Give me 5 mins.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/U8kfNbYF - Index.php
https://pastebin.com/Ahiuxazp - Functions.php
https://pastebin.com/VmpHMdc3 - Profile.php

Comment: Sorry but I have not a single clue what you are trying to acomplish with that code.. That ` <a href="profile.php?id= <?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Profile</a>` not works is pretty obvious: You dont even fetch anything into $row.. Can you provide some screenshots and a better explaination what you are trying to do?

Comment: I did, a couple of times. So you wanna know how to fetch data from a database?

Comment: Yes I need function like ```<?php echo $_SESSION['username....``` I want to know how that work..I can't find it on youtube..

Comment: I need to add this ```$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'name of db');
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<a href="profile.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Visit '.$row['username'].'</a>';
}
``` to functions.php?

Comment: `$_SESSION` will not access the database but your session. If you want to display a list of all users from your database providing links to the profile pages see my updated answer above. Then on the profile page you need to `$_GET['id']` to fetch the data from the selected user.

Comment: @reaLFOXY you comment `Yes I need function` for what?

Comment: I know ```$_SESSION``` wont help me with accessing the database,I asked you code like that ( Code who fetch data... )

Comment: I dont see your functions.php beeing included anywhere in your application but I assume you have some more code.. you can add the snipped above at the place you want to print the "list" of links.

Comment: @reaLFOXY put it where you want it.. I cant decide this for you :D

Comment: @reaLFOXY you want to fetch data in `profile.php` with `$row['id']` ?